# How do I position a <img> in-between two <ul> in a navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a navigation bar at the top the page, with the logo in the centre and a list either side. Each list containing three links to pages in the site.

For some reason, the logo doesn't scroll with the page, but .nav, #left and #right do scroll normally.

The page is live here:

[afsmma.com](http://afsmma.com)

Here's the code:

```css
.nav {
    margin: auto;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    background: #efefef;
    font-family: 'Assistant' , sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#left {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

#left li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.afs {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;

}

.afs img {
    margin: 5px auto 0px auto;
    height: 50px;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    list-style: none; 
}

#right li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.hero {
    height: 100%;
    background: url(/images/ph.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul id="left">
      <li>HOME</li>
      <li>EVENTS</li>
      <li>TICKETS</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="afs">
      <img src="images/LogoCyan.svg">
  </div>

  <ul id="right">
      <li>SHOP</li>
      <li>GALLERY</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="hero"></div>
```

Comment: If you want the logo to scroll, remove `position:absolute`.

Comment: I have tried the same code you posted, and it works fine :)
But not the live website, check if it's different..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of Flex will solve it easily and very cleanly.

Avoid position:absolute and use flex,

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/vikas_saini/v6uxh3sc/1/

CSS:

```
.nav {
    margin: auto;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    background: #efefef;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-family: 'Assistant' , sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#left {
    margin: 0;
    display:flex;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

#left li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.afs {
    flex-grow: 1;  
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;

}

.afs img {
    margin: 5px auto 0px auto;
    height: 50px;
}

#right {
    display:flex;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    list-style: none; 
}

#right li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.hero {
    height: 200vh;
    background: url(/images/ph.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">

            <ul id="left">
                <li>HOME</li>
                <li>EVENTS</li>
                <li>TICKETS</li>
            </ul>

            <div class="afs">
                <div class="image-container">
                      <img src="images/LogoCyan.svg">
                </div>
            </div>

            <ul id="right">
                <li>SHOP</li>
                <li>GALLERY</li>
                <li>CONTACT</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
         <div class="hero"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;` in the .nav class and `position: absolute` to the .hero class

Answer (score 0):

Try to align your items with flex:

```
.nav {
 margin: auto;
 height: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 900px;
 background: #efefef;
 font-family: 'Assistant' , sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

#left {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 17px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 list-style: none;
 display: flex;
}

#left li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 15px;
 font-size: 12pt;
}

.afs {
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 900px;

}

.afs img {
 margin: 5px auto 0px auto;
 height: 50px;
}

#right {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 17px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 list-style: none; 
 display: flex;
}

#right li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 15px;
 font-size: 12pt;
}

.hero {
 height: 100%;
 background: url(/images/ph.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex`, you can create some surrounding `divs` for your `ul` menus, and specify the widths of each `div` container to show the menus and logo inline. As for the hero image, moving that after open `<body>`, you can specify a `position of fixed` with a `z-index of -1` to move it behind the menu. Please see the JSFiddle that shows the new `CSS` with the actual images from your site.

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lk1ygsp/

```css
.nav {
  margin: auto;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  background: #efefef;
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#nav-left {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

#left {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

#left li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 15px;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

.afs {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.afs img {
  margin: 5px auto 0px auto;
  height: 50px;
}

#nav-right {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

#right li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

.hero {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://afsmma.com/images/ph.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

#body-container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ambition Fight Series</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant:400,700&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="hero"></div>

    <div class="nav">

      <div id="nav-left">
        <ul id="left">
          <li>HOME</li>
          <li>EVENTS</li>
          <li>TICKETS</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="afs">
        <img src="http://afsmma.com/images/LogoCyan.svg">
      </div>

      <div id="nav-right">
        <ul id="right">
          <li>SHOP</li>
          <li>GALLERY</li>
          <li>CONTACT</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="body-container">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ullamcorper volutpat nunc vehicula tincidunt. Phasellus vel urna id mi aliquam consequat non eget eros. Fusce rutrum lorem nunc, eu ultricies justo tempor sit amet. Orci varius natoque penatibus
        et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris ante velit, eleifend non nulla et, mollis blandit purus. Curabitur vehicula orci vel ultricies pretium. Donec cursus suscipit arcu, eget dignissim eros scelerisque at. Mauris a blandit
        libero. Quisque quis vehicula orci, id dapibus ipsum. Maecenas urna purus, mattis et sollicitudin eget, ullamcorper quis enim. Maecenas sagittis mi vitae justo feugiat pretium. In quis elementum sapien. Integer consequat mi vitae nisl vulputate
        feugiat. Curabitur rhoncus, lorem at fermentum sagittis, tellus metus sagittis metus, et ullamcorper massa mi sit amet metus. Mauris nec dictum orci, eu pellentesque mi. Proin maximus et lacus eget vestibulum.
      </p>
      <p>
        In tempor erat nec tristique cursus. Quisque eleifend placerat lacinia. Suspendisse lectus nibh, congue non auctor non, lacinia et erat. Donec pellentesque mi ac sapien luctus, luctus laoreet quam ullamcorper. Donec consequat est neque, id elementum libero
        iaculis sit amet. Fusce imperdiet in erat in imperdiet. Cras ullamcorper elit vel nisl efficitur ultricies. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque eu porta erat, a mattis turpis. Quisque aliquam nunc quis felis consectetur, ut interdum tortor sagittis.
        Suspendisse posuere ipsum ut ipsum sagittis viverra. Vestibulum feugiat, turpis ut vehicula dignissim, ipsum lectus efficitur magna, facilisis condimentum mi nulla sed mi. Nullam nunc dui, elementum et tellus nec, facilisis convallis libero. Mauris
        facilisis, magna ut vestibulum ornare, elit massa pellentesque arcu, sed laoreet nisi erat quis dolor.
      </p>
      <p>
        Donec ut imperdiet nisi. Nullam molestie convallis erat convallis accumsan. Suspendisse in lectus ac orci aliquet consequat. Praesent eleifend, nisl quis vulputate mollis, dui erat dignissim tortor, non mattis felis enim quis magna. Fusce posuere ante
        ac orci rutrum, ut varius lectus gravida. Curabitur tristique volutpat sodales. Fusce lobortis volutpat pretium. Integer luctus purus eu neque blandit, id rhoncus diam consectetur. Donec placerat sapien vel augue semper, consequat consequat eros
        dictum. Fusce sagittis, nibh at scelerisque finibus, lorem purus aliquam dolor, at finibus quam dui ut dolor.
      </p>
      <p>
        Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur vehicula iaculis volutpat. Nullam nibh mi, dapibus a nisl facilisis, consectetur gravida elit. Donec tempus tristique massa semper elementum. Nam mauris
        massa, aliquam in dolor ut, porttitor cursus erat. Cras pretium egestas ipsum quis ornare. Nunc sit amet ornare odio.
      </p>
      <p>
        Mauris molestie enim vitae magna venenatis fringilla. Nullam nisi dui, eleifend et erat a, sollicitudin fringilla risus. Integer molestie purus id urna tristique volutpat. Duis interdum pharetra arcu vitae consectetur. Nunc at suscipit quam. Nunc sit
        amet gravida risus, malesuada eleifend libero. Aenean quis nibh libero. Morbi ut sapien nec erat sodales tempor at in magna. Etiam pretium velit mi, quis auctor sapien fringilla sit amet. Maecenas ornare, sapien et posuere tempor, nunc justo tempus
        odio, ac sodales ipsum lacus quis nisi. Suspendisse viverra turpis at nibh blandit, id sollicitudin purus fermentum.
      </p>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ullamcorper volutpat nunc vehicula tincidunt. Phasellus vel urna id mi aliquam consequat non eget eros. Fusce rutrum lorem nunc, eu ultricies justo tempor sit amet. Orci varius natoque penatibus
        et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris ante velit, eleifend non nulla et, mollis blandit purus. Curabitur vehicula orci vel ultricies pretium. Donec cursus suscipit arcu, eget dignissim eros scelerisque at. Mauris a blandit
        libero. Quisque quis vehicula orci, id dapibus ipsum. Maecenas urna purus, mattis et sollicitudin eget, ullamcorper quis enim. Maecenas sagittis mi vitae justo feugiat pretium. In quis elementum sapien. Integer consequat mi vitae nisl vulputate
        feugiat. Curabitur rhoncus, lorem at fermentum sagittis, tellus metus sagittis metus, et ullamcorper massa mi sit amet metus. Mauris nec dictum orci, eu pellentesque mi. Proin maximus et lacus eget vestibulum.
      </p>
      <p>
        In tempor erat nec tristique cursus. Quisque eleifend placerat lacinia. Suspendisse lectus nibh, congue non auctor non, lacinia et erat. Donec pellentesque mi ac sapien luctus, luctus laoreet quam ullamcorper. Donec consequat est neque, id elementum libero
        iaculis sit amet. Fusce imperdiet in erat in imperdiet. Cras ullamcorper elit vel nisl efficitur ultricies. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque eu porta erat, a mattis turpis. Quisque aliquam nunc quis felis consectetur, ut interdum tortor sagittis.
        Suspendisse posuere ipsum ut ipsum sagittis viverra. Vestibulum feugiat, turpis ut vehicula dignissim, ipsum lectus efficitur magna, facilisis condimentum mi nulla sed mi. Nullam nunc dui, elementum et tellus nec, facilisis convallis libero. Mauris
        facilisis, magna ut vestibulum ornare, elit massa pellentesque arcu, sed laoreet nisi erat quis dolor.
      </p>
      <p>
        Donec ut imperdiet nisi. Nullam molestie convallis erat convallis accumsan. Suspendisse in lectus ac orci aliquet consequat. Praesent eleifend, nisl quis vulputate mollis, dui erat dignissim tortor, non mattis felis enim quis magna. Fusce posuere ante
        ac orci rutrum, ut varius lectus gravida. Curabitur tristique volutpat sodales. Fusce lobortis volutpat pretium. Integer luctus purus eu neque blandit, id rhoncus diam consectetur. Donec placerat sapien vel augue semper, consequat consequat eros
        dictum. Fusce sagittis, nibh at scelerisque finibus, lorem purus aliquam dolor, at finibus quam dui ut dolor.
      </p>
      <p>
        Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur vehicula iaculis volutpat. Nullam nibh mi, dapibus a nisl facilisis, consectetur gravida elit. Donec tempus tristique massa semper elementum. Nam mauris
        massa, aliquam in dolor ut, porttitor cursus erat. Cras pretium egestas ipsum quis ornare. Nunc sit amet ornare odio.
      </p>
      <p>
        Mauris molestie enim vitae magna venenatis fringilla. Nullam nisi dui, eleifend et erat a, sollicitudin fringilla risus. Integer molestie purus id urna tristique volutpat. Duis interdum pharetra arcu vitae consectetur. Nunc at suscipit quam. Nunc sit
        amet gravida risus, malesuada eleifend libero. Aenean quis nibh libero. Morbi ut sapien nec erat sodales tempor at in magna. Etiam pretium velit mi, quis auctor sapien fringilla sit amet. Maecenas ornare, sapien et posuere tempor, nunc justo tempus
        odio, ac sodales ipsum lacus quis nisi. Suspendisse viverra turpis at nibh blandit, id sollicitudin purus fermentum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```